# WKWebview loaded page does not interact properly

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to view the website https://www.methodenguide.de/basic inside a WKWebView. The website itself loads, but it doesn't behave as it should or as it does in Safari:

- The boxes on the homepage don't show images
- Links don't load targetet urls (didFinish navigation method says page is loaded instantly, but in fact nothing seems to happen)
- Navigation menu is not shown properly (compared to Safari view).

The website works perfectly in Safari on the iPhone, so there seems to be a problem with the WKWebView, but I have no clue where to look ...

Any help is appreciated, as I'm fairly new to iOS / Swift development!
Thanks in advance, everybody :)

```
    @IBOutlet weak var website: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        website.navigationDelegate = self

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.methodenguide.de/basic")!)

        website.load(request)

        website.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
        website.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.title), options: .new, context: nil)

    }

func webView(_ website: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("Began loading page")
    }

    func webView(_ website: WKWebView,
                 didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("Finished loading page")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the `info.plist`. You need to enable http (not secure) connections as the images are loaded via ajax or the certificate is not secure.

App Transport Security Settings:

```
Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content
Allow Arbitrary Loads
```

Set both to YES.

[image]